# Impossible to install Tails

Tags: tails

I tried different solution but it all failed,

First I tried to install Tails 2.4 to 8GB Kingston drive and it give error, 'insuficient free space',
Drive is tested OK, no bad sectors, I then tried different usb slots - with same results.
Then I tried to follow advice from forums to log in with password, I set password - tried to install - same result!

I used command line to install as SU, same error.

I then used 16GB kinston, exactly the same error. 32GB SD card - same result!

After that I setup VM and tried to install tails from VM, got this error:

```
Partitioning device /dev/sda
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such interface 'org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Partition' on object at path /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sda1
Tails installation failed!
g-dbus-error-quark: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such interface 'org.freedesktop.UDisks2.Partition' on object at path /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sda1 (19)
```

So this is horrible,
If anyone found the solution how to overcome this errors and install tails I would appreciate.

Comment: What method are you trying to use to write the ISO image to the USB drive?

Comment: I use Tails installer following the guide here https://tails.boum.org/

Comment: https://labs.riseup.net/code/issues/10720

Comment: How to fix installer so I can install? I failed to find solution in that page.
Also it asks for login "401 Authorization Required"

Comment: I had the same error on Ubuntu 16.04. After formatting the disk with a single FAT partition I was able to install with out any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem today.

After (!) getting the error:

- open "disks".
- Select your sdcard (be sure to select the right one - in your case /dev/sda/)
- Select the first partition.
- Click on the gear symbol.
- select "Format partition"
- select type "FAT" (should be already selected)
- click "Format"
- restart installer

Then it worked for me.