# Tails Cloning installer fails on acer chromebook 14

Tags: tails, tor-install, chrome-os

Acer chromebook 14 cb3-431-c5cq

I've booted into the primary installer [lexar 8gig]

I then open installer before plugging in the verbatim 16gig drive, select it from the drop-down and start the installer. It quickly fails and gives the output shown:

[image: installer output (186x852)]

Thank you for your time :-)

Answer (score 0):

was also discussed here: [Impossible to install Tails](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/12105/impossible-to-install-tails)

might be a solution for you aswell.